# Is there a way to prevent google search terms from matching urls?

Tags: google-search

At the moment, I am doing a number of searches which include "html" in them, for example "html rearrange".  Unfortunately, I get a lot of hits from sites that include "rearrange" on a .html page but have no mention of html in the page itself.

Is there a way to prevent search terms from matching urls?

Comment: Thanks for the answers - I didn't know about "inurl" - very useful indeed. I poked about in google and found the list of operators that can be used:
<http://www.google.com/help/operators.html>. There are some other ones in there I might find useful too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like

"html rearrange -inurl:html"

the inurl means "match the following pattern in the URL", the - means to exclude those pages

Answer (score 1):

you should actually use `rearrange intext:html`, otherwise you omit all pages ending in .html.

for example, the way matt will include www.somesite.com/rearrange.php but not www.somesite.org/better_result.html.

If www.somesite.org/better_result.html was a better result, then you might miss some important information.

Answer (score 0):

-inurl:(htm|html) "search term"

Good luck!